Gradle unable to resolve some dependencies all of a sudden
I opened my Android project after a few months and try to run it. I get this error
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.xwray:groupie:2.8.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/xwray/groupie/2.8.0/groupie-2.8.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/xwray/groupie/2.8.0/groupie-2.8.0.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/xwray/groupie/2.8.0/groupie-2.8.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.xwray:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.8.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/xwray/groupie-kotlin-android-extensions/2.8.0/groupie-kotlin-android-extensions-2.8.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/xwray/groupie-kotlin-android-extensions/2.8.0/groupie-kotlin-android-extensions-2.8.0.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/xwray/groupie-kotlin-android-extensions/2.8.0/groupie-kotlin-android-extensions-2.8.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find parts.code:money:1.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/parts/code/money/1.0.0/money-1.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/parts/code/money/1.0.0/money-1.0.0.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/parts/code/money/1.0.0/money-1.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find io.michaelrocks:libphonenumber-android:8.12.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/michaelrocks/libphonenumber-android/8.12.5/libphonenumber-android-8.12.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/michaelrocks/libphonenumber-android/8.12.5/libphonenumber-android-8.12.5.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/io/michaelrocks/libphonenumber-android/8.12.5/libphonenumber-android-8.12.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.joielechong:countrycodepicker:2.4.2

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html



This is my project level build.gradle file
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.20'
    ext.room_version = '2.4.0-alpha03'
    ext.gradle_version = '3.2.1'
    ext.KOTLIN_COROUTINES_VERSION = '1.3.6'
    ext.groupie_version = "2.8.1"
    ext.play_services_version="17.0.0"
    ext.arrow_version = "0.13.2"

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin.
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

    configurations.configureEach {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.1.1'
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

I can't seem to find the reason for such errors.

I can see libraries com.xwray:groupie on mvnrespository but the particular version 2.8.0 has been under moved under spring lib m tab. So I tried 2.8.1 which is available under JCenter tab but even that doesn't work!
I can't seem to find the library parts.code:money anywhere on the internet. It seems like it has vanished without a trace!

Did some major change happen in the last few months?

JCenter was sunsetted on August 15th, 2024: official announcement.

At the end of the sunset, all JCenter requests will automatically be redirected to Maven Central and served from there.

Some of your dependencies are available from another repositories, for example libphonenumber-android. But some seem to be no longer available, like com.xwray:groupie.

libphone-number-android is used by dependency country code picker and it uses a specific version of the library which is not avaialbe on central :( Also any idea about parts.code:money library?

I don't think it was available anywhere except JCenter @Ashwin

It's just strange the build.gradle does not have any jcenter().
Just see: https://jitpack.io/p/lisawray/groupie ...this supposedly should exist:
implementation "com.github.lisawray:groupie:2.10.1"

There others can also be looked up:
implementation "com.github.michaelrocks:libphonenumber-android:v8.13.35"
implementation "com.github.joielechong:countrycodepicker:2.4.2"

But only could find parts.code:money there (this can be added via libs directory):
http://maven.wafour.com:8081/artifactory/libs-release/parts/code/money/1.0.0/
Or alternatively, use Joda Money:
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.joda/joda-money
runtimeOnly 'org.joda:joda-money:1.0.4'


thanks, looks like xwray has been changed to lisawray. Still clueless about the other deps.

You may have loaded them from a local cache all along; while parts.code:money may have been from jcenter() indeed. Either add that linked JAR into the libs directory - or migrate to Joda Money.

I just moved my library version libphonenumberAndroid = "8.12.14"
to libphonenumberAndroid = "8.12.44" and its working for me now.
